SSO working locally but not on environment where site deployed as an app in another site
I have set up Entra SSO for a .NET Core application and it works perfectly locally on when deployed to a test environment.When deployed to live, the site is sett up in IIS as an app within another site.
the test url:
test.mysite.com/
the live url where update-my-data is the app: mysite.com/update-my-data
to test locally I have a tenancy set up on a personal account and added 'update-my-data' to the application url in launch settings.
the redirect uri is:
https://localhost:44357/update-my-data/signin-oidc
and the callback path in appsettings is '/signin-oidc'.
So far this all works perfect on local and test.
On live, I can see in the logs that the user is authenticated, but instead of being directed to the correct page after auth they get a 502 with the redirect uri shown in the browser nav.Do I have to do anything different to get this to work as expected where the site sits as an app in another site?
From appsettings.json:
"AzureAd": {
    "ClientId": "xxxxxxxx",
    "ClientSecret": "yyyyyyyyyyyyy",
    "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/zzzzzzzzz",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "AppsEditorGroup": "editor",
    "RemEditorGroup": "editor"
},

the redirect uri on azure:
https://my.site.com/update-my-data/signin-oidc
This url also appears in the browser nav after successful SSO authentication - I checked the logs for the SSO result.
SSO is initiated here:
[Route("login")]
public IActionResult Login()
{
    try
    {
       
        return RedirectToAction("home", "accounts");
        
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex, "SSO Error - Exception during authentication: " + ex.Message);
        return BadRequest();
    }
}

and I have this in the program.cs
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
    {
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false; // Adjust according to your needs
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

// Configure authentication with separate cookie authentication for Identity
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; // Use SSO as default
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; // Force SSO as the default challenge
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; // Ensure cookies are not signed in
})
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
.AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Graphv1"))
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
.
.
.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});


You need to update the Redirect URI in Azure AD to match the live environment URL . Additionally, ensure that the IIS configuration and application settings allow proper routing for the app within the parent site.

Thanks @Rukmini, the Azure RedirectURI in Azure is
'https://localhost:44357/update-my-data/signin-oidc',
in appsettings.config it is '/signin-oidc',
because the site is deployed as an app under another site in IIS, so the takes on the '/update-my-data' part by default.
This all works locally when 'update-my-data' is added to the application url in launch settings.
I can see in logs the authentication does take place, just not the correct routing

Is your live server application behind a load balancer or a reverse proxy? Would you be able to post it's configuration(redirect url, etc)? Is your application starting correctly in the live environment?

@SoftwareDveloper the application is starting correctly and the issue only began after the site was set up as an app within another site, previously is was a site on it's own and worked fine.  I will update the question with the config, I'm assuming you mean the azure config from appsettings?

I tried deploying a sample asp.net core web app with your code in my local environment in IIS as a sub app and it worked.  1. Maybe you can enable logs in your app to check for any app related errors. 2. Check the Event Viewer for any IIS related errors. 3. Check inetpub/logs.

Thanks, what I can see in the logs is the successful local environment returns a 302 after authenticating then redirects to the correct page.  On live we get the redirect uri with a 502 so I'm unclear as to whether that's server side or code, although the code does work for me.

Update cookie policy
Set-Cookie: sessionId=abc123; SameSite=None; Secure; HttpOnly

Since you are using your site in an iframe, browsers will block access to cookies, etc.
